# “How many children are you parent for?”

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality, indefinite-article

I lighted upon a sentence in a survey that struck me as odd.

> How many children are you **parent or guardian for** and live in your household?

Is it grammatical? I mean, can the indefinite article be legitimately omitted? And shouldn't it be "of" instead of "for", or does "for" also work in this context?

I thought the correct sentence would be:

> How many children are you **a parent of**?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is a little odd, but not ungrammatical. The article is not required here "He is parent of two happy children" is perfectly correct.

Normally you would use "parent of a child", but if I were to rewrite it I would use:

> How many children do you have parental responsibility for? Include only those currently living in your household.

Comment: The sentence **is** ungrammatical, albeit for a different reason. "Children" are both the subject and the object in this sentence. Whatever you wrote about the article and the preposition does apply, but the sentence really _should_ be split into two different clauses. It's not that "it's _better_ if we make two clauses out of this"—it's not just better, it's kind of a must.